# Apertar no botão de uma tela que é um fragment e ir para outra fragment. Como faz?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Eu tenho uma classe do tipo `Fragment` e gostaria que quando o usuário clicasse no botao fosse para outra tela que é fragment..como posso fazer isso?

```
public class AlertaFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alerta, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**@EDIT**

Eu coloquei assim:
Ele grifa o argumento em vermelho...

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
CadastroAlertaFragment cadastro = new CadastroAlertaFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.cadastro_frag, cadastro, cadastro.getTag());
ft.commit();
```

Erro:

```
Error:(167, 48) error: incompatible types: CadastroAlertaFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
```

Comment: O fragmento novo irá ocupar o mesmo lugar do fragmento atual?

Comment: Não.............

Comment: Como está sua classe `CadastroAlertaFragment`?

Comment: public class CadastroAlertaFragment extends Fragment {}

Comment: e tem um layout de cadastro para ele que se chama fragment_cadastro_alerta.xml e coloquei um id no layout android:id="@+id/cadastro_frag"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro do método `onClick` do seu botão, você pode fazer isso usando o método `replace()` do **[`FragmentTransaction`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)**. Veja:

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(R.id.details, new NewFragmentToReplace(), "NewFragmentTag"); 
ft.commit();
```

E se você quiser voltar para o *fragment* anterior, veja mais detalhes sobre o método [**`addToBackStack()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Estou pesquisando aqui e daqui a pouco te falo mais.

Comment: Mas lembre-se qe estou em um fragment e quero ir para outra tela....

Comment: @Aline você está em um fragment e quer ir pra outro fragment é isso né?! Ou você quer para uma activity? Agora você me confundiu

Comment: Ack desculpa. Estou em um fragment e quero ir para outro fragment

Comment: Eu sou nova no android.

Comment: @Aline então é isso mesmo que eu fiz na resposta, usando o método replace()

Comment: Deu certo.......

Answer (score 4):

Existe uma outra forma de fazer isso. E talvez seja mais simples do que pareça.

> Fragment

```
View.OnClickListener onClickHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        FragmentActivity mainActivity = getActivity();

        if(mainActivity instanceof suaActivityPrincipal)
        ((suaActivityPrincipal) mainActivity).setCurrentItemPager(1); // 1 = ID do fragment
    }

};
```

> Activity

```
public void setCurrentItemPager(int id){
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(id); // viewPager = substitua pelo seu viewPAger
}
```

É um pouco mais simples de se fazer isso. Ele faz uma referência à `Activity` pai para poder mudar o `fragment` atual.

Altere a linha: `setCurrentItemPager(1)` para o ID do `fragment` que você quer que seja mostrado.